# Installation error 80029564 on PS3

Tags: ps3, psn

I have a problem when installing the game Midnight Club Los Angeles: Complete Edition, which is available for a test of 60 minutes via the PlayStationPlus membership. All went well during the download, but when installing, 14%, I get the error 80029564. My research is not very fruitful. Many say format, others say that formatting the disk did not solve their problem. Some say try to install several times, what I do. Many talk about re-download, or even several times. I don't want to re-download 5.1go several times for only 60 minutes, especially for a game to $ 19.99.

Comment: I had the same problem with inFamous too. But from what I read, the game does not seem to make big change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say there are many suggestions to fix this error. But after reading [this thread](http://www.gamespot.com/forums/topic/25938366), it seems that you should do the following :

1. Do not download in the background.
2. Improve wireless connection if possible or use cabled connection.
3. Download the whole file in one go, to minimize risk of corrupting the download.

So right now you should restart the download, while following the directions above.

Comment: Thank you! I try this in a few weeks! inFamous = 7GB, Midnight Club go = 5.1GB. I don't do that in one day XD!